# Result values from database - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table, table1:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | MONTH | QUANTITY |
+----+-------------+----+
| 1  |   1   |     1    |
| 2  |   2   |     2    |
| 3  |   7   |     3    |
| 4  |   4   |     1    |
| 5  |   2   |     3    |
| 6  |  12   |     8    |
| 7  |   1   |     6    |
+----+-------+----------+

My file php is:

 <?php
include 'bd_cnx.php';
$ret =[];
  $sql = "SELECT 
          FROM 
          ";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0){

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      //floatval() transforma sirul numeric in numar
      $ret[] =[$row['MONTH'], floatval($row['QUANTITY'])];
          }
  }
  else {
      echo "result 0";
      }
?>
```

How can I return to the values in this form? [ [1,7],[2,5],[3,0],[4,1],[5,0],[6,0],[7,3],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,8] ]

Thank you!

Comment: what is the logic behind that output?

Comment: _How can I return to the values in this form?_ What is the rule behind this _form_?

Comment: I need this form for a chart line http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: ok, but what is the logic behind it? BTW SELECT FROM is not a valid sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code.

```
$finalArray = $store = [];
$sql = "SELECT MONTH,SUM(QUANTITY) FROM `stack` GROUP BY MONTH";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //floatval() transforma sirul numeric in numar
        $store[$row['MONTH']] = $row['QUANTITY'];
    }
    $finalArray = '[';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $finalArray .= "[$i," . (isset($store[$i]) ? $store[$i] : 0) . "]";
        if ($i != 12) {
            $finalArray .= ",";
        }
    }

    $finalArray .= ']';
} else {
    echo "result 0";
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: for line: `$finalArray .= "[$i," .(isset($store[$i]) ? $store[$i]) : 0) . "]";` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: @ster `$finalArray .= "[$i," . (isset($store[$i]) ? $store[$i] : 0) . "]";`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a temp array of your database results and then do a loop over a (fixed) set of months (1-12)

```
$tmp = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $tmp[$row['MONTH']] = $row['QUANTITY'];
}

$retTmp = array();
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    $retTmp[] = "[$i," .(isset($tmp[$i]) ? $tmp[$i] : 0) . "]";
}
$ret = '[' . implode(',', $retTmp) . ']';
```

Comment: for the line  `$ret .= "[$i," .(isset($tmp[$i]) ? $tmp[$i]) : 0) . "]";` -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\